# Objective-C: Fading GUI

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip

I want to download the zip and unzip it. When I downloaded the zip, everything works fine. But when unzip my interface stops for a few seconds and sometimes app crashes. How to fix it?

Zip File size 650 MB

downloadButton - activates downloading on button click

```
 -(IBAction) downloadButton:(id)sender{

_url1 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"link"];

_downloadTask1 = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url1];

[_downloadTask1 resume];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{

if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) {

    _paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    _documentsDirectory1 = [_paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *newLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/1.zip", _documentsDirectory1]];
    NSError *error;
    [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:newLocation error:&error];
}
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;{

if( downloadTask == _downloadTask1){
    _progress1 = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];_total1 = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];
    _percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f%%", ((_progress1 / _total1) * 100)];
    (NSLog (_percentage, @"%.f%%"));
    _label.text = _percentage;
}
if ([_percentage isEqual: @"100%"]) {
    _label.text = @«ok»;
    [self performSelector:@selector(zip) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeZip) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}
}

-(void) zip{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    _paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    _documentsDirectory1 = [_paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    _zipPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.zip"];
    _destinationPath1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_documentsDirectory1];
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:_zipPath1 toDestination:_destinationPath1];
});
}

-(void) removeZip{
_paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
_documentsDirectory1 = [_paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:[_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.zip"] error:nil];
}
```

Comment: If it crash, is there any error message in console? Do you have to unzip on main thread?

Comment: 1. I check console. No messages. App just fold. 2. If I don’t use dispatch_async app fading. If I use dispatch_async app lag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handling of threads/queues is wrong.

The NSURLSession delegate methods are called on an `NSOperationQueue`, which is a background queue unless you specifically set it up to use a queue that runs on the main thread.

Thus you can do time-consuming things in the delegate methods without blocking the UI.

However, any code that updates the UI needs to be performed on the main thread.

You can get rid of the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue` wrapper around your unzip code, since unless you take special steps, that code will be called from a background thread anyway.

However, your code in your session delegate methods that updates labels and makes other UIKit calls needs to performed on the main thread:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session 
    downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask 
    didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{

    if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) {

        self.paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDirectory1 = [_paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *newLocation = [NSURL URLWithString: 
            [NSString stringWithFormat: @"file://%@/1.zip", 
        self.documentsDirectory1]];
        NSError *error;
        [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:newLocation error:&error];
        [self zip];
        [self removeZip];
    }
}

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session 
            downloadTask: (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *) downloadTask 
            didWriteData: (int64_t) bytesWritten  
            totalBytesWritten: (int64_t) totalBytesWritten
            totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t) totalBytesExpectedToWrite; {
        if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) {
            self.progress1 = (float) totalBytesWritten;
            self.total1 =  (float) totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
            self.percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f%%", 
                ((_progress1 / _total1) * 100)];
            NSLog(@"%.f%%", self.percentage, );
    
            //Setting a label's text is a UI call so it needs to be done on the main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if ([_percentage isEqual: @"100%"]) {
                    _label.text = @«ok»;
                };
                else {
                    _label.text = _percentage;
                }
        }
    }


-(void) zip {
    _paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    _documentsDirectory1 = [_paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    _zipPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.zip"];
    _destinationPath1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_documentsDirectory1];
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:_zipPath1 toDestination:_destinationPath1];
}

-(void) removeZip {
    _paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    _documentsDirectory1 = [_paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *filename = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.zip"];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: filename error:nil];
}
```

BTW, this line is needlessly complex and inefficient:

```
_progress1 = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
```

There's no reason to create an `NSNumber` (an object that requires a memory allocation). Just cast `totalBytesWritten` directly to a float:

```
self.progress1 = (float) totalBytesWritten;
```

And, since that code runs on a background thread, you should make those properties atomic and use the syntax "self.property" to use the property's getters and setters.

### EDIT:

There are other UI calls in the method above that I did not fix. I just changed one of them as an example.

Your handling of the 100% complete case is also fragile and bad practice. Get rid of that code and move the code that invokes your (un)zip method to the download complete delegate call, and get rid of the `performSelectorwithObject:afterDelay:` wrapper around those calls.

In the download complete session delegate method, move the file, unzip it, and remove it, all without any calls to dispatch_async, since that method will be called on a background thread anyway.